# Скрипт тестирования пользователей

Tags: php

В данный момент увлечен созданием мощного портала, посвященного космонавтике. Проект на завершающем этапе. Нужен скрипт тестирования (проверки знаний) пользователей. Или ссылки на  урок по созданию тестов, в общем любой подсказке буду рад. Дополнительный вопрос: интересует ли аудиторию  программистов на форуме Российская космонавтика? 
4 февраля.

Продолжаю тему. В поисках нормального примера теста на проверку знаний нашел интересные приемы реализации. Материалы теста лежат [тут](http://quizml.webservis.ru/files/quizml-parser-sample.tar.gz). Вот только одна проблемка есть: как правильно обработать суперглобальный массив поступающий в result.php, может кто-нибудь сможет решить задачку?

Comment: ээм...возможно не всех

Comment: а точнее вообще не всех практически.

Comment: В свое время тоже искал, так ничего путного и не нашел. Пришлось писать свой костыль (это не так сложно, как может показаться).

Comment: Помнится, @cy6erGn0m туманностями интересовался :) Возможно, там не только рисовальный интерес. Я бы тоже заглянул. В любом случае, за ссылку в профиле не забанят =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблему помогли решить специалисты соседнего [форума](http://phpforum.ru/), огромное им за это спасибо!!!

Выкладываю пример обработчика полученных массивов методом POST:

```
<?php
/*
    Обработка результатов тестирования
*/

// Переменные для подсчета правильных, частично правильных и неправильных ответов
$right_answers = 0;
$part_right_answers = 0;
$wrong_answers = 0;

// Массив с развернутыми сведениями
$details = array();

// Внесение в массив данных из файла xml
foreach($test->question as $q){
    $qid = (int)$q[qid];
    $qtype = (string)$q[type];
    $text = (string)$q->text;
    $answer = (string)$q->answer;
    $details[$qid]['type'] = $qtype;
    $details[$qid]['text'] = $text;
    $details[$qid]['answer'] = $answer;
    if($qtype == 'checkbox' || $qtype == 'radio'){
        foreach($q->choice as $c){
            $caid = (int)$c[aid];
            $details[$qid]['choices'][$caid] = (string)$c;
        }
    }
}

/*
     Прием ответов пользователя
*/

// Номер вопроса
$qnum;

// Прием ответов из $_POST
foreach($_POST as $key => $answer){
        if(substr($key, 0, 3) == 'qid'){
        $qnum = (int)$answer;
        continue;
    }

    // Вносим ответ пользователя в массив с развернутыми данными
    if($details[$qnum]['type'] == 'checkbox'){
        if(substr($key, 0, 3) == 'q'. $qnum . 'a'){
            $details[$qnum]['useranswer'][] = $answer;
        }
    }
    else {
        $details[$qnum]['useranswer'] = $answer;
    }
}

/*
     Проверка правильности ответов
*/

foreach($details as $num => $det){
    if((string) $det['answer'] === (string) $det['useranswer']){
        // Если ответ совпадает:
        $score = 5;
        $right_answers += 1;
    }
    //Если ответ не совпадает
    else {
        // Если вопрос подразумевает множество ответов:
        if(is_array($det['useranswer'])){
            // Перевод правильных ответов в массив
            $rightans = explode(',', $det['answer']);

            // Общее кол-во правильных ответов
            $rqt = count($rightans);

            // Общее кол-во ответов пользователя
            $uqt = count($det['useranswer']);

            // Сравнение ответов пользователя с правильными ответами
            foreach($det['useranswer'] as $ua){
                if(in_array($ua, $rightans)){
                    $a += 1;
                }
                else {
                    $b += 1;
                }
            }

            if($b > 0) {
                // Если есть неправильные ответы:

                // Кол-во ответов всего
                $allqt = count($det['choices']);

                // Отношение кол-ва прав.ответов пользователя ко всем правильным ответам
                $r = $a / $rqt;
                // Отношение кол-ва непр. ответов пользователя ко всем ответам
                $w = $b / $allqt;

                // Оценка
                $score = ($r - $w) * 5;
                if($score < 0)
                    $score = 0;

                $part_right_answers += 1;
            }
            elseif($a < $rqt){
                // Если кол-во правильных ответов меньше чем нужно:
                // Оценка
                $score = ($a / $rqt) * 5;
                $part_right_answers += 1;

            }
            else {
                // Оценка
                $score = 5;
                $right_answers += 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            // Если вопрос подразумевает один ответ:
            $score = 0;
            $wrong_answers += 1;
        }
    }
    // Вносим оценку в массив с развернутыми данными
    $details[$num]['score'] = $score;
}

// Количество вопросов в тесте
$qcount = count($details);

/*
    Вывод результатов тестирования
*/
?>
<ul>
    <li>
        Правильные ответы: <?php echo $right_answers; ?> 
        (<?php echo ($right_answers / $qcount) * 100;?> %)
    </li>
    <li>
        Частично правильные ответы: <?php echo $part_right_answers; ?> 
        (<?php echo ($part_right_answers / $qcount) * 100;?> %)
    </li>
    <li>
        Неправильные ответы: <?php echo $wrong_answers; ?> 
        (<?php echo ($wrong_answers / $qcount) * 100;?> %)
    </li>
</ul>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>№ В</th>
        <th>Вопрос</th>
        <th>Ваш ответ</th>
        <th>Правильный ответ</th>
        <th>Итог</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($details as $num => $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $num; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['text']; ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php 
        if(is_array($row['useranswer'])){ 
            echo implode(', ', $row['useranswer']);
        }
        else { echo $row['useranswer']; }
        ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['answer']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Готовых скриптов-опросников в сети достаточно много.

- [phpQuest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpq/)
- [onlinetest/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/onlinetest/)
- [Myquiz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/myquiz/)
- [Flash Quiz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flashquiz/)
- [MultiWebQuiz](http://www.multiwebvista.com/testzone/download.php)
- [Quiz Manager](http://www.interlogy.com/products/content/quiz/)
- [DODO'S quiz](http://regretless.com/scripts/scripts.php#dodosquiz)
- ...

Ищутся скрипты по словам quiz, poll, test.

Comment: только выглядят они никудышно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть скрипт для создания и проведения тестов, который для начинающего программиста будет интересен.

- Построен по парадигме MVC
- Кеширование данных (Файловое | Apc | Eaccelerator | Memcache | Xcache)
- Встроенный шаблонизатор

Список возможностей: http://mbcsoft.ru/products/eruditioncms.html

Демо: [http://etest.mbcsoft.ru/](http://mbcsoft.ru/products/eruditioncms.html)