# Продолжение создания тест опросника

Tags: php, javascript

В предыдущем вопросе я пытался реализовать тест опросник [ссылка 1-го вопроса тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/75814/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9) и нашел интересный пример преподавателя информатики ссылка в первом вопросе. Теперь решил усложнить задачу и сделать ограничение попыток сдачи теста, а так же реализовать таймер с обратным отсчетом на странице. Вопрос к программистам : подскажите на примере как заблокировать страничку, то есть страница должна открываться полностью на весь браузер, блокируя меню и адресную строку, так что-бы у проверяемого пользователя отсутствовала возможность сохранить вопросы теста, так же должна быть заблокирована правая кнопка мыши. Напишите свои предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Никак.
Скопировать контент всегда можно. Даже если вы заблокируете мышку совсем для оперы через DragonFly для мозилы FireBug.

Заблокировать адресную строку тоже нельзя. Ее можно скрыть открыв страницу как попап окно. но одним нажатием мышки она вернется на место.

Можно просто Джаваскриптом развернуть на весь экран див и туда Аяксом подружать инфу (спасет от модификаций адресой строки для гет параметров). но от описанных выше не спасет.

А уж если кто-то очень захочет, то поставит Charles и послушает пакеты, модифицирует и вуаля.

Остается только ограничение на стороне сервера (Пхп) записывать попытки по ИП + логин.

Answer (score 0):

Заблокировать не сможешь никак.

Единственный выход из положения отслеживать выход из текущего окна браузеры, т.е. если окно становится неактивным то закрывать сессию и не давать дальнейшее продолжении теста.

Это нужно для того чтобы он не рылся по другим сайтам в поисках ответа, не лазил в другие программы а проходил тест именно в данном ему окне.

Контент всегда можно стырить, даже если ему картинками вопросы писать - это кстати еще круче тырится.

Да пусть тырит вопросы, ведь их в тесте может быть 1К штук, а для прохождения выдается всего 20-30, пусть ищет тогда все 1К вопросов и ответы к ним... это занудно и долго.

Сам дипломную работу писал **"Система тестирования знаний на базе архитектуры клиент сервер"** составление вопросов и ответов на делфях, остальное пхп и мускул с JS.

Нормальный проект получился. До сих пор работает в моём колледже и с его помощью тестят всех. пока никто не дорабатывал даже, что приятно.

Там много условий на прохождение теста. описывать все не буду.

В общем как-то так.